# VScode says there are issues with modules tht use angular ivy but it should not be a issue

Tags: angularjs, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am having a issue when using angular in VSCode.
The issue is that it says there are not ngModules, (and somehow it is because of the AngularIvy) like:

```
[{
    "resource": "[...]src/app/components/basic-info-card/basic-info-card.module.ts",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "-996002",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "'CommonModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.",
    "startLineNumber": 13,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 13,
    "endColumn": 17,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 22,
            "startColumn": 39,
            "endLineNumber": 22,
            "endColumn": 39,
            "message": "This likely means that the library (@angular/common) which declares CommonModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.",
            "resource": "not+gona+show"
        }
    ]
}]
```

but not only 'CommonModule' is part of the class (and the project)... but it also is not supposedly to have an issue with Angular Ivy, considering that I deactivated it in tsconfidg.app.json with:

```
...
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

It is supposed for us to make a module called "my-project"(I changed name obviously) inside an angular project called "project"

Please help.

Information that may be helpful

System:
Windows 10 home
Avast free

VSCODE version

```
Version: 1.80.1 (user setup)
Commit: 74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771
Date: 2023-07-12T17:22:07.651Z
Electron: 22.3.14
ElectronBuildId: 21893604
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

ANGULAR VERSION

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 8.3.17
Node: 14.21.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.17
@angular/cdk                       8.2.3
@angular/cli                       8.3.17
@angular/material                  8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.29
@schematics/angular                8.3.17
@schematics/update                 0.803.17
ng-packagr                         5.7.1
rxjs                               6.5.3
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "icons": "fantasticon"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/material": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.13",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.4.0",
    "fantasticon": "1.2.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "material-design-icons": "3.0.1",
    "ng-packagr": "5.7.1",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.17",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.803.17",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.13",
    "@types/node": "12.12.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tsickle": "^0.37.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "project:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "project:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "project:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "project:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-project": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/my-project",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/my-project/src",
      "prefix": "edge",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/my-project/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/my-project/ng-package.json"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/my-project/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/my-project/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/my-project/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/my-project/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/my-project/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "project"
}
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "my-project": [
        "dist/my-project"
      ],
      "my-project/*": [
        "dist/my-project/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I tried,

- restarting the angular server,
- deleting `node_module` and `npm install`,
- deleting `node_module` and `npm i --unsafe-perm --verbose install`,
- deleting `node_module`, `npm cache clean --force` and `npm install`,
- deleting `node_module`, `npm cache clean --force` and `npm i --unsafe-perm --verbose install`,

I really don't know what else I could do to make it work. Other people use it just fine in linux, but I use Windows, and I doubt it is the only issue.

I even tried to reinstall angular many times, but it never worked. I am running out of options and these errors impede me from making tests as I want to.

I now suspect it is something related to the vscode as I tried basically all other means that I know off

Answer (score 0):

Install an earlier version of the Angular Language Service extension, for an Angular 8 project, version v11.1.3 seems to work fine-